# Reading a few lines in Python

Tags: python, file

I've currently got an issue where I need to read N lines from a text file,
there is 50 lines total, but I want to give my user the choice of how many are picked.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Sounds like you could start with [open](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/open_function.html). That's used to read files and it supports `readline()`.

Comment: Show us that you tried something at least. What did you write so far ?

Comment: txtFile = open("random.txt",r)    idk how to go to next line. but then its : txtFile.readlines() and idk what to do from there

Comment: Good start. What now? And what's the obstacle?

Comment: @AngusBennett Could you add that to your question above?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
user_demand = int(input('how many lines?'))
if user_demand > 50:
    user_demand = 50

with open('filename.txt', 'rb') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        if i == user_demand:
            break
        print(line)
```

Comment: Why the 'rb' mode? If we're talking about a regular old text file `open` doesn't need an explicit mode since the default 'r' works fine oO

Answer (score 1):

So first of all you have to open the file:

```
txt = open(r"yourfile.txt","r")
```

Now you can read it.

```
lines = 0
for line in txt:
    if lines >= max_lines: break #max_lines is the input by the user
    #do something
    lines = lines + 1
txt.close()
```

Or you could use `readline()` to store all lines in an Array and then just print or use the amount of lines the user wants to.

Note: There are a lot of better and more efficent solutions to this task. This ist jsut a "Quick-Start" for you :)

Comment: "Note: There are a lot of better and more efficent solutions to this task." such as?

Comment: Any efficiency aside, the pythonic way of handling file objects is to open them with a context manager using `with` to ensure that they get closed once done with

Comment: Plus, you never actually read the contents of the file in your loop.

Comment: so this pythonic way seems to be more elegant :)

Comment: @sobek yes i know, this is why I added the commen #do something do you think i should add something else there ?

Comment: Not just more elegant. If your code fails to execute up to the close, you have a memory leak. The `with` context ensures `close` is called even if the program crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
# open the file
file = open("filename.txt")
# load lines into a list
all_lines = file.readlines()

# get input
amount_lines = input("How many lines do you want to print? ")
# turn input (string) into an integer
amount_lines_int = int(amount_lines)

# do something with all the lines from index 0 to index amount_lines_int (excl.)
for line in all_lines[:amount_lines_int]: 
    # strip line frome whitespace (i.g. the paragraph)
    line = line.strip()
    print(line)

file.close()
```

Comment: You wouldn't really do this. `all_lines = file.readlines()` reads the whole file into memory. The reason for only wanting a certain number of lines is usually because you want to avoid doing exactly that. You can iterate the file object without loading it into memory.

Comment: Of course the user could enter a number greater than there are lines (see the other answer) or enter a string that can't be converted into an integer (i.g. letters).

Comment: Plus you're not closing the file if something unexpected happens.

Comment: @ roganjosh You're right, but 50 lines doesn't seem much and it's a quick solution easily understandable for a beginner.

Comment: @ sobek I've seen that too and edited the answer to say "file.close()" at the end, is that right?

Comment: No, if your loop crashes, you're not reaching that `close` and that should never happen. Traditionally you would use a `try...except` construct, but nowadays you really should use the `with` context, see mehrdad-pedramfar's answer.